# How to iqnore mousemove event on child ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I am trying to create a sliding navigation bar which would move according to the cursor position on the menu bar. I have managed to move the bar with respect to the cursor but bar is moving when I am hovering over the child elements that is the sub menus of the navigation bar.A picture illustration is given below for an eagle eye view of the menu:

[image]

The problem is how can I ignore moving of the parent navigation menu on this sub menu respected code is as following:

JavaScript Code:

```
$('#cssmenu').mousemove(function(e) {
    outer_menu_width = $("#cssmenu").width();
    inner_menu_width = $("#main_nav_menu").outerWidth();
    x_position_on_navigation = e.pageX;
    possible_total_margin_left = inner_menu_width - outer_menu_width;
    percentage_of_cursor_position = (x_position_on_navigation/outer_menu_width)*100;
    margin_left_distance = (percentage_of_cursor_position*(possible_total_margin_left/100));
    $('#main_nav_menu').css('margin-left','-' + margin_left_distance + 'px');
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
            <ul style=" display: inline-flex !important;" id="main_nav_menu">
                <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
                <li class='active'><a href='#'>Products</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='#'>Product 1</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Product 2</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>

                <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
                <li class='active'><a href='#'>Products</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='#'>Product 1</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Product 2</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>

                <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
                <li class='active'><a href='#'>Products</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='#'>Product 1</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Product 2</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>

                <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
                <li class='active'><a href='#'>Products</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='#'>Product 1</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Product 2</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>

                <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
                <li class='active'><a href='#'>Products</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='#'>Product 1</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Product 2</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>

                <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
                <li class='active'><a href='#'>Products</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='#'>Product 1</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Product 2</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>

                <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
                <li class='active'><a href='#'>Products</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='#'>Product 1</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Product 2</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>

                <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
                <li class='active'><a href='#'>Products</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='#'>Product 1</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Product 2</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Contact 1</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Contact2</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Contact3</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Contact4</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Contact5</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Contact6</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Contact7</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Contact8</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Contact9</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Contact0</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Contact10</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Contact11</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Contact Last</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Last Menu</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

CSS Code:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 4;
  /*display: block;*/
  /*height: 45px;*/
  /*position: relative;*/
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;

}

#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  /*height: 45px;*/
  /*position: relative;*/
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;

}

#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  background: #00AAB5;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 17px;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  /*position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 11px;*/
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  /*display: block;*/
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';

  float: right;
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-right: -20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  /*position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;*/
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;

  display: inline-flex;
  float: right;
  margin-right: -17px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 23px;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  z-index: 99999999;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
  height: 35px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.15);
  padding: 11px 15px;
  width: 170px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  font-weight: 400;
  background: #00AAB5;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.last-item > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  /*position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 11px;*/
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  /*display: block;*/
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';

  float: right;
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-right: -3px;
  margin-top: -7px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  right: auto;
  left: 11px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  /*position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;*/
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;

  display: inline-flex;
  float: right;
  /*margin-right: -17px;*/
  margin-top: 2px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  right: auto;
  left: 14px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 17px;
  height: 0;
}
@media all and (max-width: 768px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #cssmenu {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-center > ul {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li {
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li,
  #cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
    height: auto;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li {
    float: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 25px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 35px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    color: #dddddd;
    background: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li.active > a {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
  #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before,
  #cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
  #cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button {
    display: block;
    padding: 17px;
    color: #dddddd;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    right: 17px;
    display: block;
    height: 4px;
    width: 20px;
    border-top: 2px solid #dddddd;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    right: 17px;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 20px;
    background: #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button.menu-opened:after {
    top: 23px;
    border: 0;
    height: 2px;
    width: 15px;
    background: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button.menu-opened:before {
    top: 23px;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 15px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
    height: 46px;
    width: 46px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened {
    background: #262626;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button {
    height: 34px;
    width: 34px;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    right: 19px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 2px;
    display: block;
    background: #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:after {
    top: 15px;
    right: 13px;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after {
    background: #ffffff;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 19px;
    right: 22px;
    display: block;
    width: 2px;
    height: 8px;
    background: #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:before {
    top: 12px;
    right: 16px;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:before {
    display: none;
  }
}

#cssmenu ul
{ 
  /*overflow-x:hidden;*/
  white-space:nowrap; 
  /*height: 1em;*/
  /*height: 45px;*/
  /*width: 100%;*/
} 

#cssmenu li
{ 
  display:inline; 
}       

#cssmenu {
    /*overflow-x: visible;*/
    overflow: hidden;
}

#cssmenu{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: where is the css code ?

Comment: @Amitsingh CSS Code has been added !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well a little hackish and probably not recommended:

```
$('#main_nav_menu ul').mousemove(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, so #cssmenu mousemove wont be executed.

You should add var before defining your variables as not doing so will make them global, unless you have defined them somewhere else.